# Get object value using function parameter in javascript or Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a simple function that goes like this:

```
getCurrentUserInfo: function (userId, reference) {
    var scanUser = Meteor.users.find({"_id": userId}).fetch()[0];
    return scanUser.reference;
  }
```

When user the function like this:

```
getCurrentUserInfo(Meteor.userId(), "_id");
```

It gives me "undefined" result which I believe it is due to the string parameter "_id" because it works if I return `scanUser._id` directly . I am not sure how to make it work. Any suggestion or related topic about it? Thank you.

Comment: Stephen Woods' answer below did the trick, I thought adding `[0]` at the end of my query would remove the array property of scanUser but it did not so I have to use `scanUser[reference]` and that sorted it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
getCurrentUserInfo: function (userId, reference) {
    var scanUser = Meteor.users.find({"_id": userId}).fetch()[0];
    return scanUser[reference];
}
```

You need to access properties of objects by string using bracket notation.

Comment: Stephen Woods - OMG that is quick, now I realize that the scanUser is an array so I should use array. I thought by adding [0] at the last of the query would remove the array. Thanks a lot Mr. Woods :)

Answer (score 1):

`return scanUser._id;`
since you implicitily wrote _id inside the function

`return scanUser[reference]`
which is more generic and works for any property